# How do I predict values using .predict() function in statsmodels in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statsmodels, sklearn-pandas

I have typed in the following lines of code:

```
# import relevant statistical packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pylab as pl
import sklearn.linear_model as skl
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# import data
url = "/<...>/Smarket.csv" # relative url within my computer
Smarket = pd.read_csv(url, index_col = 'SlNo')

X3 = Smarket[['Lag1', 'Lag2', 'Lag3', 'Lag4', 'Lag5', 'Volume']]
Y3 = Smarket['Direction']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X3, Y3, test_size=0.2016)
data_1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(y_train), X_train], axis = 1)
model_1 = sm.formula.glm(formula = 'y_train~X_train', data = data_1,  family= sm.families.Binomial()).fit()

X_new = model_1.predict(X_test)
```

Now it is in the last code where I recieve the following error:

```
PatsyError: Number of rows mismatch between data argument and X_train (252     versus 998)
y_train~X_train
        ^^^^^^^
```

I am just unable to understand why I am getting this error. I get it might be because of mismatch in the number of data between X_test and X_train. How do I need to change my code to get the predicted values?

Comment: Your formula does not look right to me since `y_train` and `X_train` are not columns in `data_1`. Should it be `formula = Direction ~ ['Lag1', 'Lag2', 'Lag3', 'Lag4', 'Lag5', 'Volume']` or something similar?

Comment: @QuangHoang Oh God! I feel quite stupid now! Yes, of course!!! Thank you so much.